# Height for row appointed to wrong Cell - iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a very strange problem with cell heights. Although in the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` I get the right height for each cell's textView (as showed in the log text) in the actual `UItableView` the height is appointed to the wrong cell. The height adjustment is applied to the first cell (on top) instead of the last cell (bottom) as it was supposed to. The log file is:

```
height = 73 
for cellText = inliulimkkhcelslktilkt vkr inuvilu i hkrhjknvhjkr hskn jhv ljhvsjkrhiuhiug vhriu hgiurhv kughkv s jhs hshkjh iuhguriu hgkj hgk hjkgh h
2014-01-28 13:12:03.312 anonymous[7838:70b] height = 18 
for cellText = cell add
2014-01-28 13:12:03.313 anonymous[7838:70b] height = 18 
for cellText = reload
2014-01-28 13:12:03.313 anonymous[7838:70b] height = 18 
for cellText = test again
2014-01-28 13:12:03.313 anonymous[7838:70b] height = 18 
for cellText = and another one
2014-01-28 13:12:03.313 anonymous[7838:70b] height = 18 
for cellText = lehsjgjksdk
2014-01-28 13:12:03.314 anonymous[7838:70b] height = 18 
for cellText = another one
2014-01-28 13:12:03.314 anonymous[7838:70b] height = 18 
for cellText = this is a reply test
2014-01-28 13:12:03.314 anonymous[7838:70b] height = 18 
for cellText = this is a reply test
2014-01-28 13:12:03.314 anonymous[7838:70b] height = 18 
for cellText = this is a reply test 1
```

but in the actual running of the app the actual positions of the cells are exactly opposite (large text on bottom of the list going up) meaning that the `73.0f` height is applied to "this is a reply test 1". Any suggestions?

in the cellForRow..:

```
NSDictionary *dic = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
dic = [passedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
message = [dic objectForKey:@"message"];
NSLog(@"message = %@",message);
username1 = [dic objectForKey:@"username"];
if ([username1 isEqualToString:username]) {
    cell1.textView.text = message;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    UIImage *imageNotCropped = [UIImage imageWithData:[defaults objectForKey:@"profileImageData"]];
    NSLog(@"image: %@",imageNotCropped);
    cell1.imageView.image = imageNotCropped;
    cell1.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    cell1.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    cell1.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    cell1.textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-UltraLight" size:16];
}else{
```

in the heightForRow:

```
 NSString *cellText = [[passedArray objectAtIndex:passedArray.count-indexPath.row-1] objectForKey:@"message"];
 UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-UltraLight" size:16.0];
 NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: cellFont};
CGRect rect = [cellText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(225, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                               options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                            attributes:attributes
                                               context:nil];
NSLog(@"height = %.f \nfor cellText = %@",rect.size.height, cellText);
return rect.size.height;
```

Comment: post your relavent code

Comment: I just edited the question with the actual code. Thanks

Comment: You are retrieving objects from passedArray is wrong in cellForRowAtIndexPath method. copy same code from heightForRow method.

Comment: that worked.. thanks.. I missed that part..

Comment: in your cellForRow method, try doing `dic = [passedArray objectAtIndex:passedArray.count-indexPath.row-1];` instead of `dic = [passedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

Answer (score 0):

This is likely what is causing the error:

```
 NSString *cellText = [[passedArray objectAtIndex:passedArray.count-indexPath.row-1] objectForKey:@"message"];
```

Change it to:

```
 NSString *cellText = [[passedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"message"];
```